# Is there any other way to change windows local user password beseide this one /c net user " + user + " " + newPass; via C#

Tags: c#

the main problem is that windows will in some future disable to modify users password like this method below, and I need to get some other approach beside this one.

```
static void batchCMD(string user, string newPass)
    {

        try
        {
            Process cmdProcess = new Process();
            cmdProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            if (System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6)
            {
                cmdProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
            }
            cmdProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            cmdProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            cmdProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

            cmdProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c net user " + user + " " + newPass;
            cmdProcess.Start();

            cmdProcess.WaitForExit(10000);
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\temp\txt.log", DateTime.Now + " " + "HIUHIUHIUH" + "\n");
        }
    }
```

If you have some other and better solution please share with me.

Comment: I don't know for sure but I'd be surprised if you can't do it via PowerShell, maybe look it up

Comment: *windows will in some future disable to modify users password like this*. Where did you read that?

Comment: Have you done any research whatsoever?  It seems like you'd find the answer pretty quickly with a simple Google search.

Comment: @dotNET The `NET` command-line program has had a number of features removed or deprecated in recent Windows releases, so it's reasonable to assume that Windows' command-line interface isn't as stable as the Win32 API. Examples include `net name`, `net print`, `net send`, `net start/stop`, etc.

Comment: @Dai That *still* does not answer dotNET's question.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto yea you was right I managed to find the solution that I need.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Win32 `NetUserChangePassword` function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netuserchangepassword

The C# P/Invoke signature is available here: https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/netapi32.netuserchangepassword

```
[DllImport( "netapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true )]
static extern UInt32 NetUserChangePassword
(
    [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPWStr )] String domainName,
    [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPWStr )] String userName,
    [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPWStr )] String oldPassword,
    [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPWStr )] String newPassword
);
```